# In Regular Expression, how to make an alternative to "?" matching by only using union (+) and closure(*) quantifiers?

Tags: regex, regular-language, automata

I would like ask if is it possible to represent "?" quantifier using only union (+) and closure(*) quantifiers.

For example, "a+" can also represented as "a(a*)". How can you represent "a?" with only "*"s and "+"s?

Comment: You could use the {0,1} which means match at least 0 occurences of previous char or at most 1

Comment: It's not possible with just `+` and `*`. You'll need alternation (`(a|)`) or capture groups and lookarounds (`(a(?!\2)())*`) or maybe some other tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I raised up this question because I'm stuck in one of the questions of our mock exam in automata. We're only allowed to use union(+), closure(*), and concatenation expressions to describe every language.

Comment: @Rawing sounds like an answer to me, you should post it

Answer (score -1):

`a?` can be represented as a + ε
and, as mentioned, `a+` can be represented as `aa*`.

Comment: What is ε in "a + ε"? It doesn't looks like regular expression.